# Using our Own Oauth Authoriztion and Social Login Authorization in same server

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

We would like to have REST APIs with OAuth2 using our own user table for Authentication. Also, we need to allow Social Login. Below is the flow for social login,

Our OAuth

1. Client makes auth and access token URL for our servers to receive
   the access token
2. Client sends access_token for further calls in the header as bearer
   token

Social Login

1. Client makes auth and access token URL to Social Login server(For
   ex,https://accounts.google.com/) to receive an access token
2. The client sends access_token for further calls in the header.

We have implemented our OAuth with Spring and working perfectly. We have questions on social login,

1. How to identify our own Oauth access token and social login access
   token. We may have many social logins and we should able to identify corresponding social login.
2. How to validate and integrate with Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the access tokens are just random strings, you probably cannot tell the issuer of the provided token and you cannot validate it.

I would suggest you to extend your OAuth2 server to accept third party providers (Google, Facebook ...) for authentication. This way would support both local and social users, but in your application, you would always deal with your own tokens. It would make the application security much easier (which usually means safer) and you could also configure your own scopes for access tokens. There are also ready to use solutions for it - e.g. [Keycloak](http://www.keycloak.org/).

Comment: I just extended my OAuth2 server with social logins with the tutorial https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-boot-oauth2/tree/master/auth-server