# Integrating Social Logins with own OAuth2 REST API server

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, oauth-2.0

I am trying to make a mobile app in React-Native and Server in Spring-Boot which have a OAuth2 implemented API endpoints. 
My question is how can I integrate Social Logins into my React-Native app which in save a user in my user table. apart from Social login I am using naive register/login flow which require username/password to provide access token from OAuth2 Server. How can I do the same with Just Social Login without prompting user any password or other extra information.

any general solution for this will help regardless of tech I am using.
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48339760/731178), it might discuss the same problem as your have.

Answer (score 0):

Usually when using social networks to login/sign up you'll get a token returned in your app which you can send via your REST API and on your backend it can then retrieve the users information from the social platform used depending on the granted scopes(e-mail, username, etc...) and store the retrieved values in the database.

Thats basically how it works in general, but if you want to have more information you probably still need to share some more info about your tech used.

Hopefully that helped you out ;)